# C++/CLI DLL on C# doesn't compile

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop

I wrote a wrapper DLL for some native c++ functions and compiled it in c++/CLI, then I added a reference to C# project, functions indicates there, but when I try compile project I get this error:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'lib, Version=1.0.3742.39593, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64-bit vs 32-bit incompatibility is the most common cause of that error.

In the [Project settings page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx) of the C# project your `Platform target` will be set to `Any CPU`. This means that on a 64-bit system the program will run in a 64-bit process. It will then be unable to load DLLs that target 32-bit (native DLLs can't switch to suit the process.)

So you need to set it to x86. In VS2010 the default will be x86 for new projects.

Comment: DLL and C# project has been written in 32-bit enviroment

Comment: And the host c# program is being built and run on a 32-bit OS?